# Retrieve attribute with max value by group

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-analyst, dissolve

I have a intersected counties shapefile with wind potential category attribute. What I want to do is to dissolve the features grouping them by county, and retrieve the WPC value which has the largest AREA. With `Dissolve` tool i am able to retrieve the area only.

Here is the data snippet:

[image]

So my desired output would be a layer with 1 feature for county with WPC value (with max Shape area).

Comment: Look at the [help page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm). Dissolve by country field and max statistic on sum shape.

Comment: Thanks. With Dissolve tool I was able only to get SUM_Shape value, but I need WPC as well.

Comment: To get corresponding WPC of max area, join dissolve layer to original layer on area, you can include any fields you want.

Comment: Sort descending by area, remove duplicate by country. Also I suggest removing spatial analyst from tags.

Comment: A simple summarize with max option on WPC will produce a table. Also subqueries are supported in ArcMap selects, which means you can use summary operations such as max to select. I don't have time now to find an example.